# Delete timeout on one record

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to delete one record from a table in sql server but for somereason the delete is taking ages.

I have tried going into `EDIT TOP 200 ROWS` and still nothing.

There is only one row in the table so i do not see the problem.

The table structure is as follows.

FitterId (int) | FileName (nvarchar(50)) | Extention (nvarchar(10)) | FileData (Image)

EDIT : 
I have also tried updating, and DROPing the table.

Comment: Is there a foreign key with cascading deletes on it?

Comment: @user3083310 It is a newly created table so there are no foreign keys or primary keys.

Comment: if you check activity monitor on the database in question, do you see anything in "Resource Waits" specifically under "locks"? If you're unsure how to check this, read this: http://www.sqlshack.com/sql-server-activity-monitor/